# Proof that if $a≤b$ then $a<b+{\epsilon}$

Tags: real-analysis

As shown [here](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Real_Plus_Epsilon), if we have two real numbers $a$,$b$ and any real ${\epsilon}$ greater than zero, then if $a<b+{\epsilon}$ then $a≤b$. How to prove the converse, namely that $a≤b$ implies that $a<b+{\epsilon}$?

Comment: It's a basic property of inequalities: $b<b+\varepsilon$, hence by transitivity, $a<b+\varepsilon$.

Comment: That's an awkward way of phrasing that result. It is important in these cases to learn to phrase things carefully. The language above is confusing. The statement is "If, (for all $\epsilon>0$, $a<b+\epsilon$) then $a\leq b$." Your phrasing seems ambiguous - the second "then" seems to be tied to the "if $a<b+\epsilon$." The "then" result is deduced from the "for all ..." sentence, not just from one $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $\forall \epsilon >0$ we have $b<b+\epsilon$.

Now,

if $a=b$ than $a=b<b+\epsilon$

if $a<b$ , by transitivity of the order relation, we have $a<b+\epsilon$